# Scikit-Learn Logistic Regression Memory Error

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm attempting to use sklearn 0.11's LogisticRegression object to fit a model on 200,000 observations with about 80,000 features. The goal is to classify short text descriptions into 1 of 800 classes.

When I attempt to fit the classifier pythonw.exe gives me:

Application Error "The instruction at ... referenced memory at 0x00000000". The memory could not be written".

The features are extremely sparse, about 10 per observation, and are binary (either 1 or 0), so by my back of the envelope calculation my 4 GB of RAM should be able to handle the memory requirements, but that doesn't appear to be the case. The models only fit when I use fewer observations and/or fewer features.

If anything, I would like to use even more observations and features. My naive understanding is that the liblinear library running things behind the scenes is capable of supporting that. Any ideas for how I might squeeze a few more observations in?

My code looks like this:

```
y_vectorizer = LabelVectorizer(y) # my custom vectorizer for labels
y = y_vectorizer.fit_transform(y)

x_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(binary = True, analyzer = features)
x = x_vectorizer.fit_transform(x)

clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(x, y)
```

The features() function I pass to analyzer just returns a list of strings indicating the features detected in each observation.

I'm using Python 2.7, sklearn 0.11, Windows XP with 4 GB of RAM.

Comment: Did the Python interpreter crash? Writing to `0x0` is a pretty grave error, we (scikit-learn developers) should look into it.

Comment: The Python interpreter does crash.

Comment: Is the dataset you are using public? Can you reproduce this crash with a smaller dataset (for instance with `x_first_half = x[:x.shape[0] / 2]` or `x_second_half = x[x.shape[0] / 2:]`?

Comment: Unfortunately the dataset isn't public, but I'll try to recreate the problem on a public one. The classifier fits fine if I use either half of the observations, or if I set a max_features cutoff of about 50,000 in CountVectorizer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

liblinear (the backing implementation of `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression`) will host its own copy of the data because it is a C++ library whose internal memory layout cannot be directly mapped onto a pre-allocated sparse matrix in scipy such as `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` or `scipy.sparse.csc_matrix`.

In your case I would recommend to load your data as a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` and feed it to a `sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier` (with `loss='log'` if you want a logistic regression model and the ability to call the `predict_proba` method). `SGDClassifier` will not copy the input data if it's already using the `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` memory layout.

Expect it to allocate a dense model of 800 * (80000 + 1) * 8 / (1024 ** 2) = 488MB in memory (in addition to the size of your input dataset).

**Edit:** how to optimize the memory access for your dataset

To free memory after dataset extraction you can:

```
x_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(binary = True, analyzer = features)
x = x_vectorizer.fit_transform(x)
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(x.tocsr(), 'dataset.joblib')
```

Then quit this python process (to force complete memory deallocation) and in a new process:

```
x_csr = joblib.load('dataset.joblib')
```

Under linux / OSX you could memory map that even more efficiently with:

```
x_csr = joblib.load('dataset.joblib', mmap_mode='c')
```

Comment: Excellent answer, you provide better support for this free software than others give for very expensive software, the world owes you many thanks. One minor note though, the SGDClassifier's predict_proba method only seems to be implemented for 2 category classification tasks.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot about that. There is currenly a discussion on the mailing list to add proper multinomial logistic regression to SGDClassifier or to implement Platt's scaling or variants for predicting probabilities in a one-vs-rest multiclass setting.