# scikit-learn: Running Logistic Regression `fit` giving memory error for dataset with 55,000 training samples and 5000 features each

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am using a dataset which originally has 4 columns out of which 2 columns are numerical and two are categorical. I used `one hot` encoding by using `pandas` `get_dummies` function for the two categorical columns. One of these columns had low cardinality and it gave no issues but the other had close to 5000 distinct values. For that I used, `sparse=True` in get_dummies function. The function worked fine and then I split my data to training and test data using the following command:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[fields],df['category_id'])
```

Here `df` is the pandas dataframe, `fields` is a list of field names which includes the two numeric field names and the new field names that I got from one hot encoding.

Then I am using the following code to train the model:

```
import sklearn.linear_model as lm
classifier = lm.LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py", line 1142, in fit
    order="C")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 510, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 373, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
MemoryError
```

How can I overcome this and what is the recommended way of running the logistic regression for relatively larger datasets ?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195395/scikit-learn-logistic-regression-memory-error. Look into using a gradient descent approach with the dataset as a scipy sparse matrix

Comment: Nice! I had checked out that answer but was unsure if the relationship between x_train (converted to a sparse matrix) and y_train will be maintained. The fit function did execute without any issues. I am now evaluating accuracy