# how to avoid upscaling / copy of data in scikit-learn Logistic Regression's fit() for dense input data

Tags: scikit-learn

I have a large input data set of type float16. My data is dense, not sparse.

I use sklearn's LogisticRegression class to fit a model to that data.

I am running out of memory during model fitting.

I believe fit() will upscale to either float32 or float64, depending on the solver used and/or the version of sklearn.

Is there a way I can avoid this extra data copy and/or upscaling?

Would upscaling the input data myself to float64 avoid the data copy?

My preference is to use the liblinear solver, but will consider lbfgs or saga.

I'd prefer not using gradient descent.

Comment: Looking at the source code, for check_array [https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841d57e8b5f6b2a570312e9d832e69debc/sklearn/utils/validation.py#L350], there is no extra copy produced during the cast (copy = false when np.astype is called).

Comment: It looks like you've seen this already but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195395/scikit-learn-logistic-regression-memory-error is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thanks. So you think loading my data as a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix and feeding it to a sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier would work for dense data as well?

Comment: Yes, the idea of the sparse matrix implementations in scipy is primarily to save on storage where possible by leveraging the number of 0s.  In the case of dense matrix data, there just won't be many (if any) memory savings from the optimizations.